# How to load files from a subfolder instead of root folder in htaccess?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

my test website is **frontshoppe.com**

and I have the following `.htaccess` below.

```
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^frontshoppe\.com$
    RewriteRule (.*) http://www.frontshoppe.com/$1 [R=301,L]
    RewriteRule ^$ admin [L]
```

Yes it is loading fine like i wanted it to load the contents of the admin folder.. 
But I would also like the url to be..

> www.frontshoppe.com ONLY.. 
> and not
>   www.frontshoppe.com/admin

Comment: r u using any framework? MVC? Is your website and admin folder are in same directory? more info please

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should work:

```
RewriteEngine on

# Change yourdomain.com to be your primary domain.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?frontshoppe.com$

# Change 'subfolder' to be the folder you will use for your primary domain.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/admin/

# Don't change this line.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# Change 'subfolder' to be the folder you will use for your primary domain.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /admin/$1

# Change yourdomain.com to be your primary domain again. 
# Change 'subfolder' to be the folder you will use for your primary domain 
# followed by / then the main file for your site, index.php, index.html, etc.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?frontshoppe.com$ 
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ admin/index.php [L]
```

Comment: How can I add another subdirectory? like /blog redirects to the blog folder

Answer (score 0):

You can have your rules like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^frontshoppe\.com$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+admin/(\S*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [L,R=302,NE]

RewriteRule ^((?!admin/).*)$ admin/$1 [L,NC]
```