# laravel app displays laravel file structure when accessed on browser

Tags: php, laravel, cpanel

My laravel app displays the file structure when I attempt to access it on a browser using a domain name. I need my app to use a secure connection (HTTPS) however,
on the browser I get a file structure. Please view the screenshot and .htaccess code below. I'd appreciate help in getting a browser to display website content.

[image]
[image]

My .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R,L]
```

**Below is what I get on the browser when I access the domain name**

[image: view screenshot here]

Comment: The domain should point to the public folder, not to the root

Comment: What are you using to serve your site, e.g. nginx, apache etc...?

Comment: Hi, please I don't quite understand. Could you point it out with a code snippet? I'd appreciate

Comment: @RJK, its Apache

Comment: @Philly what exactly do you not understand? Your domain points to the root folder of your application, it should point to the public folder of your app. Share your hosts file, or where you define your domain pointers.

Comment: @Frnak do you mind a little code snippet? thanks

Comment: @Philly What is the value of `DocumentRoot` in `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf` or `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/default-ssl.conf` (if you have SSL enabled)?

Comment: @GertB. @Frnak do you mean `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.yourdomain.com/public$1 [R,L]` ?

Comment: @Philly no, not in your htaccess, ln your vhosts file, where you've set your domains document root. like RJK commented

Comment: @GertB. do you mean the public_html folder?

Comment: @Philly No, first of all: your application should not be in public_html. this means the Laravel code is in a public folder, thats a security risk. Your Laravel public folder should be the root folder for your domain. On your server there is a file where your define the root of your domain (now public_html). Thats what you need to change. Depending on your server you need to change the files RJK commented, or in the control panel of the server. Since you don't understand this, maybe ask your hosting provider?

Comment: @RJK `etc` folder does not contain the file you pointed out. contained in it are a folder and a cacheid file

Comment: Guys I just uploaded screenshots of my cpanel for more clarity. I'm yet to solve this problem. All files host files in `resources/views` folder.

Comment: In cpanel -> go to domains (or subdomains if it is a subdomain), click the manage button for the domain, there you can change the document root.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26541754/how-to-load-files-from-a-subfolder-instead-of-root-folder-in-htaccess